# How to check check box true or false in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a check box. I need when this check box is checked then the controller action will get all the related data, if it is not checked it will not.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <col class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                <th class="text-center">Sl. No</th>
                <th class="text-center">Date</th>
                <th class="text-center">Receipt No.</th>
                <th class="text-center">Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @result.each do |r| %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag 'infos[]',r.v_amount %>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center"><%= check_box_tag "deatils[]" ,r.v_amount,{} ,:id => r.id %></th>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.id %></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.c_date %></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.Receipt_No %></td>
                <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i><%= r.v_amount %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @ Sebastiaan : this table is inside a form whose action is add_payment.I can not know how i will get checked data inside this.

Answer (score 0):

Add class 'related_data' to the checkbox field

```
<%= check_box_tag "deatils[]" ,r.v_amount,{} ,:id => r.id,class: 'related_data' %>
```

Then write a coffee like this:

```
jQuery(".related_data").live 'change', ->
  jQuery.ajax '/controller/action_to_get_data',
    type: 'POST'
```

I hope you get an idea to solve your problem.